# How to add dimension to a tensor using Tensorflow

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I have method `reformat` in which using numpy I convert a `label(256,)` to `label(256,2)` shape.

Now I want to do same operation on a Tensor with shape (256,)

My code looks like this (num_labels=2) :--

```
def reformat(dataset, labels):
  dataset = dataset.reshape((-1, image_size, image_size,num_channels)).astype(np.float32)
  labels = (np.arange(num_labels)==labels[:,None]).astype(np.float32)
  return dataset, labels
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use [tf.expand_dims()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/expand_dims) to add a new dimension.

```
In [1]: import tensorflow as tf    
        x = tf.constant([3., 2.])
        tf.expand_dims(x, 1).shape

Out[1]: TensorShape([Dimension(2), Dimension(1)])
```

You can also use [tf.reshape()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/reshape) for this, but would recommend you to use expand_dims, as this will also carry some values to new dimension if new shape can be satisfied.

```
In [1]: tf.reshape(x, [2, 1])
Out[1]: TensorShape([Dimension(2), Dimension(1)])
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, expand_dims() looks good but how to add this step- labels = (np.arange(num_labels)==labels[:,None])  in Tensorflow ?

Comment: Please note (num_labels=2)

Comment: @Anuj Easiest way to see values inside a tensor is to `eval` it or run it with `tf.Session()`. I am not sure what you do there and if you can do it differently but to compare variables inside a tensor you need to use session. Like this `sess.run(x) == sess.run(tf.expand_dims(x, 1))`

Comment: In that I can think of only 1 approach converting this Tensor into numpy array and then operating (np.arange(num_labels)==labels[:,None]) on that numpy array, finally wrapping it back into tensor.
Is that best approach in your view?

Comment: It would be better if you can do all the manipulation you want on a numpy array and finally wrap it into a tensor, tensors are made to flow =). But If you can't help it, and can't do it on tensors, yeah.