# Tensor reshape from (256, 256, 3) to (1,256, 256, 3)

Tags: python, tensorflow

My question is how can I reshape the tensor!

Here is one syntax `tf.reshape(tensor, shape, name=None)`

i do not know , where am i going wrong but i am not able to reshape

how can i do that?

thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add dimension to a tensor using Tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42708652/how-to-add-dimension-to-a-tensor-using-tensorflow)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
axis=0

# image is your tensor

tf.expand_dims(your_image, axis)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `tf.expand_dims`:

```
output = tf.expand_dims(input, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code:

```py
#assuming `img` contains the data which is in the format (256,256,3)
output = tf.reshape(img, [1, 256, 256, 3]) # 1 is batch size
```